# custClrList of PowerPoint presentation

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop, office-automation

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint library to work with PowerPoint presentations and looking for a way to programmatically modify 'Custom Colors' section of color palette. I can see that it's stored inside 'custClrList' tag in ppt->theme files and can be modified manually, but not sure how to access it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint custom colors are saved to the XML file, so if you want to re-use it on another machines you need to think including such files to the installer. For example, here is a VBA sample which creates a custom theme and saves it to a file:

```
Sub mkThemeCols()
With ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Theme
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent1) = RGB(255, 0, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent2) = RGB(0, 255, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent3) = RGB(0, 255, 255)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent4) = RGB(255, 255, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent5) = RGB(23, 255, 10)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent6) = RGB(23, 255, 100)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeDark1) = RGB(23, 0, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeDark2) = RGB(23, 23, 23)
.ThemeColorScheme.Save Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Colors\myNew Theme.xml"
End With
End Sub
```

It is also possible to add XML so that there are extra color schemes that travel with the presentation (method on [Echo Swinford's site](http://echosvoice.com/wp-content/uploads/pptfiles/code2.txt))